# Extract number from class using xpath

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been trying to extract a number of bedrooms, bathrooms, etc. from the following class but somehow I can only either extract the first part of the list (even when I check if it contains the word):

Here is what I have now:

```
[69]: garages = response.xpath('//ul[@class="pro-list features"]/li[@class="features_item--numeric"][contains(., '" Garages"')]/span/text()').extract_first()

In [70]: garages
Out[70]: '1'
```

And as a result, I somehow only get 1.

Here is how the class looks like:

```
<ul class="pro-list features">
 <li class="features_item--numeric">
   <span>3</span>
   " Bedrooms"
 </li>
 <li class="features_item--numeric">
   <span>3</span>
   " Bathrooms"
 </li>
 <li class="features_item--numeric">
   <span>4</span>
   " Garages"
 </li>
```

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have a typo in there (`contains(., '" Garages"')` should be `contains(., ' Garages')`), but once it's fixed, I can't replicate your problem.

Comment: @JackFleeting  when I remove double quotes I get nothing as the output, it's so weird.. maybe a link can help [http://www.chaskahomes.co.za/residential/constantia/house-for-sale/3199797]

Comment: What happens if your drop `.extract_first()` from `garages`?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
response.css('li:contains(Garages) span::text').extract()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//ul[@class="pro-list features"]/li[@class="features_item--numeric"][contains(., "Garages")]/following-sibling::span/text()
```

It matches the `<span>` tag after the `<li>` element which contains the text `Garages` (and not `" Garages"` which is *not* part of the `<li>` element and would require a completely different approach).

Or use the `<span>` inside of the `<li>` element:

```
//ul[@class="pro-list features"]/li[@class="features_item--numeric"][contains(., "Garages")]/span/text()
```

Comment: I've tried both of these but then I get nothing as the output, I think something is up with space there.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath should do the trick (example with 'Garages') once you've downloaded and parsed the html:

```
//li[substring-after(normalize-space(),' ')='Garages']/span/text()
```

Working XPath for the online webpage :

```
//li[normalize-space(text())='Garages']/span/text()
```

Working XPath for the XML you posted :

```
//li[contains(.,"Garages")]/span/text()
```

or

```
//li[substring-after(normalize-space(),'" ')='Garages"']/span/text()
```

Comment: I've tried all of them but I'm unable to make any of them work.. with the last one (that seems like it should do the job) I get the following error `ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in //li[substring-after(normalize-space(), ')='Garages]/span/text()` 
It must be something with the quotes?

Comment: Do you paste the XPath correctly ? Did you try with .get() instead of extract_first()?  What's the result with this XPath (Garage without s is not a typo) :`//li[substring-after(normalize-space(),"Garage")]/span/text()` ?

Answer (score 0):

using this xpath selector you can easily get what you are required just changing the text accordingly 
    //li[normalize-space(text())='Garages']/span/text()